# C# - How to get only Date part from string 'd MM YYYY HH:mm:ss AM/PM'

Tags: c#

In my C# project, there is a modal with string field which holds DateTime value.

*User.cs*

```
string DateOfBirth { get;set;}
```

I am trying to convert it to DateTime field and get only date part to use in another function 
*UserService.cs*

```
accountDateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(user.DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

I get 'String not recognised as a valid datetime' error at this line.

How can I get only date part from a date time string field.

Comment: Show us the values of `user.DateOfBirth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just the Date part of the DateTime, you need to use the .Date property of the DateTime.

```
DateTime accountDateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(user.DateOfBirth).Date;
```

You might be assuming that use of DateTime.ParseExact with format provided will give you the format you need, that is not correct. ParseExact looks for the string to be in that format so that it can properly parse it.

You should also know that if `accountDateOfBirth` will contain the Time part in it as well, it will simply be 12 AM (because its part of the DateTime field.

If you need to print only the Date part of the DateTime, use

```
string accountDateOfBirthString = DateTime.Parse(user.DAteOfBirth).Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

This will give you the format you want.